# Save file as Tab delimited text and spreadsheet

Tags: csv, spreadsheet

I am using the following command line in Linux to save the content of my input file (txt file consisted of columns) as a spreadsheet:

```
less input_file > out_put.csv
```

my output file is 
[image]

The problem is in the output spreadsheet; all the columns in the input file stuck together in one column of the output file (spreadsheet CSV).

How can I revise my simple code to make it more efficient to save my txt file as a tab delimited text and a spreadsheet.

Comment: can you post (example) output data of `less input_file`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and use the provided [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to include it in your question instead. That way, we can actually copy it and try to answer your question. In addition, you need to tell us what program you are using to see the spreadsheet and if you are telling it to use space as a column separator (hint: you aren't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `less` is just a pager, it is a tool that lets you read files. What you're doing is exactly the same as copying input_file to out_put.csv (`cp input_file out_put.csv`). You're not changing the content in any way.

So, to read it as a spreadsheet using, for example `libreoffice`, you would need to open your spreadsheet application, then open your `input_file` and use space as the column separator:

[image: libreoffice text import dialog with spaces chosen as separator]

Now, if you really want to convert your file to *comma* separated values format (`.csv`), you would need to add commas. This command will replace all spaces with commas on each of your lines and save the output as `output.csv`:

```
sed 's/  */,/g' input_file > output.csv
```

The command above is `sed` and here I am using its [substitution operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x23170.html). The general format is `s/pattern/replacement/` which will replace `pattern` with `replacement`. The `g` at the end makes it replace *all* occurrences of the pattern on each line, without it, it would only replace the first. The pattern I gave it was  (a space) followed by 0 or more (that's what `*` means) spaces (`*`) and I told it to replace with `,`. This basically means "replace any occurrences of one or more spaces with a comma".

Comment: Thanks BUT The output file is totally distorted please [check](http://tinypic.com/m/iehzy1/1)

Comment: @MJA yes, it looks like you didn't use two spaces (`sed 's/  */,/g'`) as I did but one (`sed 's/ */,/g'). Please copy/paste the command directly to your terminal.

Comment: @MJA that _is_ magic :). It's called [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and here, I'm using the substitution operator. See my updated answer for an explanation of how the magic works.

Comment: This is great! I highly appreciate your explaination

Comment: Why use `<SPACE><SPACE>*` instead of `<SPACE>+` ?  edit: oh I guess the `+` needs to be backslash-escaped, unless you pass `-r` to sed, and you want to keep it simple?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma exactly :) And `-r` is a GNU extension so I thought I'd keep it simple.

Comment: @terdon. how can I add titles to the output.csv file. i.e title for every column?

Comment: @MJA just make sure they are there in your input.